# How to copy paperclip uploads into new model/S3 bucket?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, paperclip

I've done a code rewrite of an app and part of that means models with a somewhat different schema.

One of those models is a `Photo` model that uses Paperclip to handle the uploads to S3.

The new model stores the photos in a different bucket and with a different naming scheme, plus there are new photos sizes.

So what I need to do is copy the original photos from one S3 bucket, and then run them through my new `Photo` model so they get moved to the new S3 bucket and have their appropriate thumbnails generated.

The old data is stored in an `OldPhoto` model in the same database.

I'm running Rails 3.2 and Ruby 1.9.2 along with Paperclip 2.7.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would download all the old photos from S3 to my local hard drive.

Then, I would write a dedicated action in a controller that would parse the old-photo directory on your local drive and for each photo, find back the corresponding user/object and update_attribute on this user/object, defining the new file ( =old photo) as the new photo attribute and do the corresponding upload to the DB. Paperclip would then handle the generation of new formats and new paths to S3

My answer might look obvious, but in case it helps...